# Python POST string data

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to post the string data and I am able to do it using curl but not using requests module of python.

CURL example:

```
curl -XPOST "https://hostname/apisyntax?queryparams" -d  "key1=value&key2=value&key3=vlaue&key4[]=value"
```

This is the python example which is not working:

```
data_api = '"key1='+str(value1)+'&key2='+str(value2)+'&key3='+str(value3)+'&key4[]='+str(value4)+'"'
```

`call_api = requests.post (url, data=data_api)`

I am not getting any python error but the target server is reporting error that key4 is not found.

Please help in understanding where is the issue with python code.

Comment: Does key4 exist on the server?

Comment: yes, as this is working fine using curl.

Comment: Why does `&key4[]` in your Python request have `[]` when the other keys do not?

Answer (score 0):

Send the params as `json` instead of `data`, your final code should look something like this -

```
data_api = {'key1': str(value1), 
        'key2': str(value2), 
        'key3': str(value3), 
        'key4': [str(value4)]} 

call_api = requests.post (url, json=data_api)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_api = '"key1='+str(value1)+'&key2='+str(value2)+'&key3='+str(value3)+'&key4[]='+str(value4)+'"'

call_api = requests.post (url, data=data_api)
```

I notice an inconsistency there in `key4`, which is the one that is giving you trouble.

Try

```
data_api = '"key1='+str(value1)+'&key2='+str(value2)+'&key3='+str(value3)+'&key4='+str(value4)+'"'

call_api = requests.post (url, data=data_api)
```

I.e remove the `[]` after `key4[]`

Comment: I know it sounds weird that [] is there in key4 but the syntax is like that only. I have tried using son and removing [] from string but both are resulting in same error.

Comment: This is an API from nagios and the syntax is very much strict. That is the reason I am saying when I pass the same thing using curl -d option, it works but not using python.